# PATCH'ing Related Data ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a `Job` class with many `JobBudgetItem`s. I am implementing a PATCH method on the controller using Microsoft's built-in JsonPatch library. The issue I'm having is when I try to update a field in a `JobBudgetItem`, EF Core doesn't persist the change. Instead it creates duplicates of each existing `JobBudgetItem` with a different Id.

### Job

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<JobBudgetItem> JobBudgetItems { get; set; }
```

### JobBudgetItem

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Category { get; set; }

public int JobId { get; set; }
public Job job { get; set; }
```

### GET /Job/1

```
  {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test", 
        "jobBudgetItems": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "category": "ATestCategory",
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "category": "BTestCategory",
            }
       ]
 }
```

### PATCH /Job/1

```
[{
    "op": "replace", "path": "/jobBudgetItems/0/category", "value": "CTestCategory"
}]
```

### JobsController

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PartiallyUpdateJob(int id, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<JobDTO> patchJob) 
{

    var jobFromRepo = await _jobManager.GetJobAsync(id);
    var jobUpdateDto = _mapper.Map<JobDTO>(jobFromRepo);
    patchJob.ApplyTo(jobUpdateDto);

    _mapper.Map(jobUpdateDto, jobFromRepo);
    await _jobManager.UpdateJobAsync(jobFromRepo);

    return Ok(_mapper.Map<JobDTO>(jobUpdateDto));

}
```

### Repo

```
    public async Task<IDataOperationResult> UpdateJobAsync(Job job) {
        _context.Jobs.Update(job);
        try {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return new OperationResult(true);
        } catch {
            return new OperationResult(false);
        }
    }
```

How can I make an update to a JobBudgetItem persist in the database?

Comment: it looks like you need to share your `UpdateJobAsync` method, not `CreateJobAsync`

Comment: @set Oops, I'll get that updated. Thanks.

Comment: In your JobsController, after the second map from `jobUpdateDto` back to `jobFromRepo`, does your `jobFromRepo` still have it's id? Could it be that it was nulled by the map and therefore ef creates a new object?

Comment: @Riscie thanks for sparking that thought. That was my problem.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that my implementation of AutoMapper is what threw things off. I opted to ignore the ID on my `JobBudgetItemDto` (the child record) which was in turn causing the original ID to vanish when it was mapped back before saving to the database.

```
        CreateMap<JobBudgetItem, JobBudgetItemDTO>()
            .ReverseMap();
            //.ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.Ignore()) // Removed this line.
```